# Creating an Icon theme with a single file size 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, icon-themes

Is it practical to use a single file size for an icon theme for Unity + 16.04 ? If yes, what file size should be optimal ? Kindly share the mandatory files and folders required for an icon theme to work. Thanks.

Comment: "File size"? Why don't you download an icon theme, for example Papyrus, and see of what files it is made up?

Comment: Icon themes like Papirus are " advanced ". I want to know more about the basic icon theme structure and scope. Thanks.